# javascript json get data names out for object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, key

Still newbie @this, hope not a silly question.

I get from a java backend a json.
For this question I assigned a with that json string.

```
let a={"status":"ok","data":[{"blablaMOUTI blablaDAN":"","blablaDAA blablaALHAZO":"","blablaMAR blablaBDAN":"","blablaHIM blablaDAN":""}]};
let b=a.data;
let s="";
for (i in b) {s += b[i]};

$('#msg').html(s);
```

As output I get object Object (small capital, big capital)

In the end I need to run over "data' and print or store that keynames :  blablaMOUTI blablaDAN , blablaDAA blablaALHAZO ... on screen or in a simple array list.
The values after the keynames or a empty string, that's fine, I need only the keynames.

Found some semi simular questions, but I don't get it to work. The answers I found all trust I know already the keynames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```js
let a={"status":"ok","data":[{"blablaMOUTI blablaDAN":"","blablaDAA blablaALHAZO":"","blablaMAR blablaBDAN":"","blablaHIM blablaDAN":""}]};

var keys = [];
for(i = 0; i< a.data.length; i++){
   for(var k in a.data[i]) {     
    keys.push(k);
   }
}

console.log(keys)
```

For testing purpose this will populate an array with keys that you wanted, but you can manipulate the result as you wish

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(a.data[0]);

Output:  ["blablaMOUTI blablaDAN", "blablaDAA blablaALHAZO", "blablaMAR blablaBDAN", "blablaHIM blablaDAN"]
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames

Answer (score 1):

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(a.data[0]);

Output:  ["blablaMOUTI blablaDAN", "blablaDAA blablaALHAZO", "blablaMAR blablaBDAN", "blablaHIM blablaDAN"]
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames